# Changing database sqlite to mysql in Flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm studying Flask Python and the tutorial that I'm following is:
[Tutorial Flask Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwZwr5Tvyxo&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH&index=1)
But the tutorial is using SQLite and I want change to MySql, so I not altered nothing and the url I set like mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost/miradi
But I'm receving this erro:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'user.username' in 'field list'") [SQL: 'SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.image_file AS user_image_file, user.password AS user_password \nFROM user \nWHERE user.email = %(email_1)s \n LIMIT %(param_1)s'] [parameters: {'email_1': 'diogo@3ia.com.br', 'param_1': 1}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)
```

What is doing?

Comment: Ah! this error occurred in this moment: user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!
Was the column name with mistakes.
I love this framework because to change the database is very easy, just alter the url, cool.